# How to execute "top" only 1 time in QNX (c++ programming)

Tags: c++, posix, qnx, qnx-neutrino, posix-api

I am trying to write simple application for QNX. I installed qnx momentics ide, connected it to QNX virtual machine, and trying to execute "top" command

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    system("top");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And i am getting and getting result until i kill "top" process manually in QNX virtual machine.
But i need only 1 time. Any ideas ?

Comment: `top -n 1` would achieve that on Linux.  Dunno if the QNX version accepts the same inputs, but `man top` (or whatever QNX uses instead of `man`) would tell you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/utilities/t/top.html) suggests you should change `system("top")` to `system("top -i 1")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
top -i 1
```

is the correct syntax to get only one iteration.  `-n #` is for node count.